# Dell Inspiron Duo crashes when I plug in my charger

Tags: power-management, dell

Good Evening everyone,

My Dell Inspiron Duo likes to just crash out when I plug in my charger!! But I'm a bit lost how to diagnosis is - Ideas??

Comment: Perhaps your charger is not fit for the Dell Inspiron Duo. Try the native Dell charger instead.

Comment: It is a native Dell Charger - I was wondering how can I capture what ever error codes are generated, so I can fix it! Thanks for the edit, and moving over to ask ubuntu! I forgot about this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching off ACPI seems to work as temporary fix:

Edit GRUB's config file by opening a Terminal window and enter :

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash clocksource=hpet acpi=off noacpi usbhid.quirks=0x00eef:0x725e:0x40"
```

Save the file and update GRUB with the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

All works perfectly now - plugging in and out of power. The `usbhid.quirks` part in the GRUB line is to help identify the touchscreen correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion - I will be trying this out a little later!

Comment: Worked like a charm - And touch screen working as well! Nice! Thank  you